# Ich habe ihn eingeladen. Aber er ist nicht gekommen

Tags: word-order

Darf *aber* auch bei einem Hauptsatz vorne stehen?

Ich würde vermuten, dass "Er ist aber nicht gekommen." die richtige Form wäre. Ich kann das aber nicht begründen.

Ist *aber* in diesem Kontext ein Adverb/Partikel?

Comment: Ich hätte eher ein Komma statt dem Punkt erwartet.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ich eigentlich auch, aber "Ich habe ihn eingeladen. Er ist aber nicht gekommen." würde ja funktionieren. Daher frage ich mich, ob man im zweiten Satz nun die Reihenfolge auch ändern kann, ohne ein Komma zu setzen.

Comment: Der Foreneditor bietet zur Auszeichnung fett, kursiv und unterstrichene Darstellung an. Es gibt keinen Grund den Gebrauch zu verweigern. Unterstreichungen sind im Netz ungünstig, da sie sehr stark mit Links assoziiert werden, aber es bleiben ja noch fett und kursiv. Außerdem benutzt man da, wo diese Möglichkeiten nicht bestehen, doppelte Anführungsstriche. Der Apostroph ist ein Auslassungszeichen oder wird sporadisch in Zeitangaben verwendet oder für Bogenminuten.

Comment: Auf Deutsch ist das : `ich lud ihn ein, er kam jedoch nicht`

Comment: @MaxMuster 'im Präteritum' fehlt, oder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es ist nicht verboten, "aber" an den Satzanfang zu stellen. Es gilt oder galt als schlechter Stil, und ich würde es in sehr formellen Texten nicht tun.

Um es zu vermeiden, kann man die Wortreihenfolge ändern, andere Wörter wie "allerdings" benutzen oder einfach die Sätze per Komma trennen.